# how can i get the coordinates of vector from point abd it is orientation angle

Tags: c++

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6QC7.png)

Ihave two points with known coordinates 
**i (xi ,yi )
k(xk,yk)**

I want to get a Vector fk in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6QC7.png) containing a coordinate  to find the angle between two vectors of orientation of target k  (fk) and( ki). I know my beginning coordinates k , angle of rotation of target k  and distance fom k to point i .
**how can i get the coordinates of vector fk  and angle beween the two vectors in written red**

Comment: Are you using a vector class from a 3rd party library or implementing your own? Do you need help with the math? Or just with implementing it in code?

Comment: yes i need help with math pleaase

Comment: This website is for questions about computer programming. I suggest you consult a calculus text book or use google to find a more appropriate site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for help with mathematics not programming.

Comment: yes i know but i need informations in math for implementing it

Comment: Then you should find a website that is about math. Figure out how to do the calculations by hand before trying to write any code.

Comment: Perhaps [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking) is a better fit. Yes I linked to the Asking help page. It's the best place to start if you aren't familiar with Mathematics.